# Importing data from excel to teradata error error code 3706 Expected something between ')' and Insert

Tags: import, import-from-excel, teradata-sql-assistant

I get an error upon importing an excel in the format:

```
"hdr1", "hdr2", "hdr3", "hdr4", "hdr5", "hdr6", "hdr7"

"value1","value2","value3","value4","value5","value6","value7"
```

Error statement:

Error executing query for record 1:  [3706] Syntax error: expected something between ')' and the 'INSERT' keyword.

I am using the SQL Teradata Assistant. I tried putting a `';'`   between the `Create Table` and the `Insert`, but that did not help. Teradata expects it to be just one statement.

CREATE TABLE STATEMENT:

```
 CREATE SET TABLE database_name.table_name ,FALLBACK ,
             NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
             NO AFTER JOURNAL,
             CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
             DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO
            (
              value1 VARCHAR(1000),
              value2 VARCHAR(1000),
              value3 VARCHAR(1000),
              value4 VARCHAR(1000),
              value5 VARCHAR(1000),
              value6 VARCHAR(1000),
              value7 VARCHAR(1000)
            )

        INSERT INTO database_name.table_name  VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?....);
```

Comment: No, Teradata expects it to be two separate statements.

Comment: I just added a ; and get a "Only 1 statement is allowed for this type of import"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue the CREATE first as a separate request.
Then toggle "Import Data" on, execute the INSERT as a separate request, and toggle "Import Data" off.

Comment: Great. Some progress. Now I get: Error importing batch records 1 - 20:  [3707] Syntax error, expected something like ')' between '?' and '".."'.
Only 0 rows were loaded.

Comment: i think the ... might not be standard teradata syntax. I might need to count columns

Comment: Correct. Remove the "…." from the INSERT. You should only have 7 parameter markers or literal values (or however many columns are in the real table), separated by commas.

Comment: Thanks, worked. The import is super slow. I have 5 million records. at the current rate, it will take 2 days (and maybe even timeout)..lets see.

Comment: With SQL Assistant, using .NET connection is generally faster than ODBC. It can also help to increase the default "batch size" in Tools/Options/Import.

Comment: But with large imports you may want to use another tool, e.g. Teradata Studio (which offers additional load optimizations via the "Data Transfer Perspective") or the TPT command-line utility.